# Python : NoneType error in isalpha() function

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror, nonetype, isalpha

I am currently stuck at problem with NoneType and using function isalpha() in Python. What I want to do is lexical analysis and I want to devide the whole code into four categories. Here is my code

```
import sys
import keyword  #keyword.iskeyword()

**strong text**def check_chars(tmp,x):
if (tmp == "" or tmp.isalpha()) and (x =="" or x.isalpha()):
    if keyword.iskeyword(tmp):
        print("Key: "+ tmp)
        return ""
    return tmp+x    
if tmp.isalpha() and not x.isalpha():
    print("Var: "+tmp)
    return x        


separators = ['(',')','[',']','{','}',',',':','.',';','@','=','->','+=','-=','*=','/=','//=','%=','@=','&=','|=','^=','>>=','<<=','**=']
operators = ['+','-','*','**','/','//','%','<<','>>','&','|','^','~','<','>','<=','>=','==','!=']

f = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
program = f.read()

tmp = ""
for x in program:

tmp = check_chars(tmp,x)
if tmp in separators:
    print("Sep: "+ tmp)
    tmp = ""
if tmp in operators:    
    print("Ope: "+ tmp)
    tmp = ""
if x is " ":
    tmp = ""
```

When I reach end of a first line in a sample program which is this:

```
def funkce(a,b):
c=''
a**=b
if a<b:
    print('ahoj\'ky',a)
else:
    print(0xff,0b11101,0o777,.90e-10,123E+5,c)
    print('''To je dlouhy
    retezec pres mnoho
    radku''')
funkce(-256+356,.85**.33)
```

An error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "HW09.py", line 24, in <module>
tmp = check_chars(tmp,x)
File "HW09.py", line 5, in check_chars
if (tmp == "" or tmp.isalpha()) and (x =="" or x.isalpha()):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isalpha'
```

I wouldn't be surprised if the error rises at the beggining of the program. But how is possible that it rises at the end of line? Is it possible that the error is somehow connected with end of line character "\n". Thank you for suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that not all of the paths through your `check_chars()` function return a value. Therefore, sometimes (specifically, in your case, when `tmp` contains `'\n'`) this:

```
tmp = check_chars(tmp,x)
```

assigns `None` to `tmp`, and then the next time you call `check_chars()`, this:

```
tmp.isalpha()
```

attempts to call `isalpha()` on `None`, and causes your problem.

The solution is to make sure all paths through `check_chars()` return a value.

Comment: Thank you for your help Paul :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Paul Griffiths. I suggest you put the checking for separators and operators before using check_chars() or inside it, as this causes an error due to the returned tmp. Note: numbers aren't handled.

Here is the full output which happens when the errors are handled, so that you reference on cases to handle. Note: I use return "" when using "except" in check_chars(), just to avoid another error next time. I also use "x = x.strip()" before inputting x to avoid newline/whitespace chars (unless you want them).
Also note I use "<<" and ">>" to contains the values of the variables.

```
Key: def
Var: funkce
Sep: (
Var: a
Sep: ,
Var: b
Sep: )
An error occurred. x=<<>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: c
Sep: =
An error occurred. x=<<'>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: a
Ope: *
An error occurred. x=<<=>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: bifa
Ope: <
Var: b
Sep: :
Var: print
Sep: (
An error occurred. x=<<a>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: hoj
An error occurred. x=<<k>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: y
An error occurred. x=<<a>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: else
Sep: :
Var: print
Sep: (
An error occurred. x=<<x>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: ff
Sep: ,
An error occurred. x=<<b>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<1>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<0>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<,>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<o>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<7>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<,>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<9>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<e>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<1>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<,>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<2>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<E>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<5>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<c>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: print
Sep: (
An error occurred. x=<<'>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<T>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: ojedlouhyretezecpresmnohoradku
An error occurred. x=<<'>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<>>, tmp=<<None>>
Var: funkce
Sep: (
An error occurred. x=<<2>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<6>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<3>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<6>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<.>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<5>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<*>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<3>>, tmp=<<None>>
An error occurred. x=<<)>>, tmp=<<None>>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

(To readers: Is there some way to minimise this output, e.g. spoiler?)